Visual Studio Code has "^C " before running the code everytime

Everytime i ran the code, it has this ^C and a blank line before running the code, it just a visual clutter in my terminal. How can i solved this extra ^C and blank line issue? i try uninstalling too, but it is still there.
Try to press backspace in the terminal but doesnt work

This typically means that you have typed "Ctrl+C" as for stopping some program.

yeah, i expect it was cause by copy shortcut i done. just that i dont know how to get ride of it

nit: it's not every time
